# Find a & b to satisfy maxima at $f(2)=1, f(x)=axe^{b(x^2)}$

Tags: derivatives

I managed to derive $f'(x)$ & $f''(x)$, according to my research im supposed to count $f'(2) = 0$(?) which would give the following expression:

$f '(2) = a(e^{4b} + e^{4b} \cdot 8b) = 0$ , how am i supposed to find the values for $a$ & $b$? i'm really lost and dont know how to continue. I would greatly appreciate a helping hand.

Thanks.

Comment: Your equation implies that $a=0$ (which contradicts existence of maxima) or $e^{4b}\left(1+8b\right)=0 \implies b=-0.125$. Second equation would be $f(2)=1$.

Comment: Could you clarify the typing of the function, please ? Is it $f(x)=\frac 1{a x e^{bx^2}}$ ?

Comment: Hi Claude, f(x) is updated in the title.

Comment: Hint: the function f and the logarithm of the function f have a maximum at the same location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips, but i'm still struggling on finding a solution, i tried using Galc127's advice and put -0.125 as b in f(2), solved a but the answer is not correct...

Comment: Problem solved, thanks Galc127 & everyone else.